# "FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed." Tuning Random Forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

Trying to train a random forest classifier as below:

```
%%time 

# defining model
Model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1)

# Parameter grid to pass in RandomSearchCV
param_grid = {
    "n_estimators": [200,250,300],
    "min_samples_leaf": np.arange(1, 4),
    "max_features": [np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1),"sqrt"],
    "max_samples": np.arange(0.4, 0.7, 0.1)
}


#Calling RandomizedSearchCV
randomized_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=Model, param_distributions=param_grid, n_iter=50, n_jobs = -1, scoring=scorer, cv=5, random_state=1)

#Fitting parameters in RandomizedSearchCV
randomized_cv.fit(X_train_over,y_train_over) ## Complete the code to fit the model on over sampled data

print("Best parameters are {} with CV score={}:" .format(randomized_cv.best_params_,randomized_cv.best_score_))
```

And I get the following error:
"610: FitFailedWarning: Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan."

Any idea if I have an error in the code?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging these in general, check `randomized_cv.cv_results_` to see which parameters have that issue, and whether it's a problem for every train-test split or just one.  Also consider setting `error_score='raise'` to get a full error traceback instead of the masking `FitFailedWarning`.

In this case, I believe it's the `max_features` space:
`[np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1),"sqrt"]`
is not a flat list, but a list of only two elements, one of which is itself an array.  The search will try to set `max_features=np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1)`, which won't work.  You can fix this by, e.g.
`list(np.arange(0.3, 0.6, 0.1)) + ["sqrt"]`